# Issue with configuring JaversSQLRepository with OpenJPA 2.4.1

Tags: javers

We have auditing requirement where all changes at entity level needs to eb logged. I'm facing issue while configuring the JaVers.

I tried getting hibernate session from entity manager, it was giving me error. I tried putting the below code for creating JaversSQLRepository and facing issues.

sqlRepository = SqlRepositoryBuilder
                    .sqlRepository()
                    .withConnectionProvider(connectionProvider)
                    .withDialect(DialectName.POSTGRES).build();

Its giving me exception as follows - Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: EntityManager can not be unwrapped to an instance of "interface org.hibernate.Session".

Can you please suggest on how ot resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box support for Open JPA in JaVers. Javers-Spring integration for SQL depends on Hibernate & JPA:

- `javers-core` -- platform independent
- `javers-persistence-sql` -- platform independent, depends on `javers-core`
- `javers-spring-jpa` -- depends on Hibernate/JPA and `javers-persistence-sql`
- `javers-spring-boot-starter-sql` -- depends on `javers-spring-jpa`